# Nested list manipulation - extract info about frequency

Tags: list-manipulation

The output of MovingMap with a nested Tally will result in a list of nested lists.  For example:

```
dex = {x, x, x, z, x, v, x, v, v, z, z, v, x, z, v, z, z, x}

sol = MovingMap[Tally, dex, Quantity[3, "Events"]]

{{{x, 3}}, {{x, 2}, {z, 1}}, {{x, 2}, {z, 1}}, {{z, 1}, {x, 1}, {v, 
   1}}, {{x, 2}, {v, 1}}, {{v, 2}, {x, 1}}, {{x, 1}, {v, 2}}, {{v, 
   2}, {z, 1}}, {{v, 1}, {z, 2}}, {{z, 2}, {v, 1}}, {{z, 1}, {v, 
   1}, {x, 1}}, {{v, 1}, {x, 1}, {z, 1}}, {{x, 1}, {z, 1}, {v, 
   1}}, {{z, 2}, {v, 1}}, {{v, 1}, {z, 2}}, {{z, 2}, {x, 1}}}
```

The aim is to create from list "sol" a new list containing frequency values so it would look like the following

```
{3,2,1,2......}
```

Thank you in advance for suggestions

Comment: Maybe just `sol // (Nest[Map, Last, 2] /* Catenate)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Last /@ Flatten[sol, 1]
```

> {3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
Join @@ MovingMap[Values@*Counts, dex, Quantity[3, "Events"]]
```

> {3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way.

```
Length /@ Join @@ Gather /@ Partition[dex, 3, 1]
```

> {3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
>    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}